# Supremum And infimum True or false

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

If the sets A and B have maxima and A ∩ B $\neq$ 0 , then A ∩ B has a maximum.

Is this statement is true or false ?

How to do these kind of problems

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed for this question. Could you please tell me how to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider $A=(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ and $B=(0,1)\cup\{3\}$. Both sets have maxima, 2 and 3 respectively. But $A \cap B=(0,1)$ which has no maximum.

Comment: How can we say that A∩B=(0,1) has no maximum ?

Comment: State the definition of maximum.